# Prolog - explanation of cut in max predicate?

Tags: prolog

Currently trying to get my head around cuts in prolog. I'm going over the LPN book and working through examples.

An example of a cut is:

```
max(X,Y,Z) :- X =< Y, !, Y = Z.
max(X,Y,X).
```

I'm confused as to why `max(2,3,2)` won't return true by matching the second rule. It fails the first rule after trying to unify Y with Z because `3 /= 2`. But in the second rule, `X = 2` and `Y = 3` so it should match. I feel like I'm missing something with how cut works and have been sitting here drawing search trees trying to work out exactly what's going on all to no avail.

Would be great if anyone can clear up for me why `max(2,3,2)` is invalid. Thanks.

Comment: Think I've sussed it out. The cut `!` means that after `X =< Y` is true (which it is in my query), the cut is automatically true, and we have committed to the first rule - that is, we cannot backtrack and use the second rule even once we realise the first rule fails, thus `max(2,3,2)` does not even trigger (so to speak) the second rule because of the commitment to the first rule caused by the cut. Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: You are correct. Since the first rule will succeed through the cut, the cut in the first rule prevents Prolog from backtracking and trying the second rule. Without it, then `max(2,3,2) would succeed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :)